# Selenium Fails to Load Page Intermittently

Tags: python, selenium

I've been pulling my hair out over this issue. I have selenium open a website and suddenly it fails 3/4 of the time. I have the same issue with chromedriver and geckodriver. It doesn't appear to be any kind of bot detection because it does work intermittently. I have no idea but I was leaning towards some kind of cookie/session issue because the site just displays a white page complaining about a failed login but I wasn't logging in. To be clear nothing is being done on the page I'm just loading it with get().

What could be the the difference between an instance of chrome opening a web page and one controlled by selenium?

Edit: I did just notice, it seems to work far more often if I go to google first. Then load the page I want. I'm so confused!

Edit 2: After some upgrades to the OS and using selenium_stealth, I've been able to get the application to run consistently but only when running it remotely via "ssh root@some-system -Y python3 bot.py" If i try to run it locally it fails. How could this be? Could it be relying on some x11 component that's not on the remote system?

Comment: Perhaps if you collect information from the server response, or check the browser console, you will see something more informative about the error.

Comment: That's were I checked first. There are no errors in the console. I checked the network tab and nothing seems different except that the response is a different page.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of various factors. The page may take some time to load a site based on our internet connectivity. So we can use wait to give enough time for the page to load.

1. Wait until an element is visible / clickable

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately it's definitely not a wait condition issue. I have waits in place but the page I'm receiving is just an error page. Something is causing an error on the websites back-end.